# What is the best way to implement notification about property change?

Tags: java, model-view-controller, listener, javabeans

A have a bean (POJO-like) and want to make model for GUI component of it. So I need to notify about each property change in order GUI component can reflect.

How to do this? Should I put notification and listener storage code just inside my bean? But this will make it "dirty". May be write some wrapper? But this will duplicate getters and setters.

Are there any libraries and/or helper objects for this in Commons or somewhere else?

**UPDATE**

Also suppose I have `AbstractList<E>` implementation. How to "propertize" it quickly, i.e. make it to notify listeners about changes? For example, by firing `ListDataEvent`. I know I can implement `AbstractListModel<E>` instead of `AbstractList<E>` but it looks worse. I wish to stay mostly "pojo-like"...

Comment: You make use of [`PropertyChangeSupport`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/beans/PropertyChangeSupport.html).  Listener support is out lined in [Writing JavaBeans Components](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/javabeans/writing/index.html)

Comment: And how to quickly "propertize" the list? So that it report about element change?

Comment: “I wish to stay mostly ‘pojo-like’”, this does not make any sense. An object sending events is an object sending events, regardless of whether you subclass `AbstractListModel` or re-invent the wheel by implementing the event stuff by yourself. The result is the same, an object sending events, regardless of whether you would call an object sending events a POJO or not.

Comment: @Holger I could extract interface from the pojo and make separate decorator class for sending events, implementing this interface. But this looks complex

Comment: Also. It is said (many years ago) in `DefaultListModel<E>` javadoc that it "will" be a collection in future versions. Future still not came.

Comment: That’s right there were a lot of promises about future features… However, to my experience an object implementing a general `Collection` interface and automatic event notification at the same time is not a good idea. The problem is that a lot of operations on a `Collection` have invalid intermediate state that should not be reported. E.g. swapping two elements consists of two set operations and in-between them one element is contained twice while the other is missing. Thus, you don’t want to notify the UI in between these two set operations. And now think of what `Collections.reverse(…)` does…

Comment: There is `FXCollections.reverse()` for this, have a look at my explanation below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at `FXCollections` (JDK 7):

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

list.add("s1");
list.add("s2");

ObservableList<String> observableList = FXCollections.observableList(list);

observableList.addListener(new ListChangeListener<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onChanged(Change<? extends String> change) {
        while (change.next()) {
            if(change.wasAdded()){
                System.out.printf("added: %s, from: %d, to: %d%n", change.getAddedSubList(), change.getFrom(), change.getTo());
            }else
            if(change.wasReplaced()){
                System.out.printf("replaced: %s, from: %d, to: %d%n", change.getAddedSubList(), change.getFrom(), change.getTo());
            }
        }
    }
});

observableList.add("s3");
observableList.set(1, "s1-new-value");
```

This will result into an output:

```
added: [s3], from: 2, to: 3
added: [s1-new-value], from: 1, to: 2
```

Comment: I see no `FXCollections` in JDK 7?

Comment: My environment is JDK 7u40, Idea 12.1.6. `FXCollections` is in `$JRE_HOME/lib/jfxrt.jar`, so my guess is that may be you have an old JDK version which was not bundled with JavaFX or your IDE doesn't add `jfxrt.jar` to the classpath by default.

Comment: Well, now change the two `add`s at the beginning to `Collections.addAll(list, "x", "v", "l", "c", "w", "k", "h", "g", "f");` and add at the end something like `Collections.sort(observableList);` or `Collections.reverse(observableList);` and think about whether you really want such a notification when the list might be *really* large. Recall that normally a single change event with the affected range is enough for such a reordering operation.

Comment: Well, it very much depends on the use case. In most cases you won't have dramatic changes to your collections in UI. For the cases you mentioned there is `FXCollections.reverse()` and `FXCollections.sort()`, when you create a view for your collection. If major and frequent updates is really a problem, one can apply throttling technique from [RXJava](https://github.com/Netflix/RxJava), i.e. render a single update for 500ms time period.

Answer (score 3):

You can either make use of something like `PropertyChangeSuppport` or roll your own, for example...

```
public class Person {

    private String name;
    private final PropertyChangeSupport support;

    public Person() {
        this.support = new PropertyChangeSupport(this);
    }

    public void addPropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
        support.addPropertyChangeListener(listener);
    }

    public void addPropertyChangeListener(String propertyName, PropertyChangeListener listener) {
        support.addPropertyChangeListener(propertyName, listener);
    }

    public void removePropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
        support.removePropertyChangeListener(listener);
    }

    public void setName(String value) {
        if (name == null ? value != null : !name.equals(value)) {

            String old = name;
            name = value;
            support.firePropertyChange(name, old, name);

        }
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }                       
}
```