# How to instantly access data from an object while that data is being modified through a loop

Tags: java, multithreading, loops, field

There is the code

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        // A running ball
        class Ball {
            private double x, y, radius, xvel, yvel;
            private long timeframe;
            private boolean moving;
            public Ball(double x, double y, double radius, double xvel, double yvel, long timeframe) throws InterruptedException {
                super();
                this.x = x;
                this.y = y;
                this.radius = radius;
                this.xvel = xvel;
                this.yvel = yvel;
                this.timeframe = timeframe;
                this.moving = true;
                while(moving) {
                    // The next print line is what i want to run outside of this constructor
                    System.out.println("x:" + getX() + "   " + "y:" + getY());
                    move();
                    Thread.sleep(timeframe);
                }
            }
            private void move() {
                x += xvel;
                y += yvel;
            }
            public double getX() {
                return x;
            }
            public double getY() {
                return y;
            }
            public void setXvel(double xvel) {
                this.xvel = xvel;
            }
            public void setYvel(double yvel) {
                this.yvel = yvel;
            }
        }

        Ball ball = new Ball(0, 0, 1, .5, .5, 1000);
    }
}
```

Now i want to access ball's x and y field while it
is running. I cannot do ball.getX() here because 
there is a loop inside of the constructor that 
to finish first.
how can i do this while the loop is running.
have an idea of using threads but i can't see 
implementation details..

Comment: do u mean how to implement notification about property change?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19853764/what-is-the-best-way-to-implement-notification-about-property-change

Comment: Having an infinite loop in the constructor seems very weird. You should probably move that loop to some function called `start` or something like that, and then run that in another thread. [This](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_multithreading.htm) may help.

Answer (score 2):

Good evening Mac JalLoh,

I think what you are searching for is the synchronized Java keyword:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html
along with the Executor framework introduced in Java 7:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html

In brief, if you want the ball moving, and if an exterior observer has to read the trajectory, you probably need two different threads, the two of them being synchronized when accessing the same object. The fact is in Java you can't modify the position of the ball AND read it at the same time. Why ? Because you can never be sure as of when the position has been updated. This causes uncertainty in position-reading and writing (look up to thread-safety in google). We do not like uncertainty so we put synchronized keyword (you can say that it is first-arrived first-served).

Also, it is not a good practice in my opinion to include the ball mouvement in the Ball constructor. In fact, the constructor answers the question "What is a ball (a 3D object with origin and radius)", whereas the translation or rotation movements answer the physical problem of motion. These two problems needs to be decorrelated (you could introduce an external object that acts on the Ball instance)

Answer (score 0):

I think i finally found the solution to what i needed.There is the code

```
public class Main {
// a running ball
public class Ball extends Circle implements Runnable{
    private double xvel, yvel;
    private long timeframe;
    private boolean moving = true;

    public boolean isMoving() {
        return moving;
    }

    public void setMoving(boolean moving) {
        this.moving = moving;
    }

    public Ball(double x, double y, double radius, double xvel, double yvel, long timeframe) {
        super(new Point(x, y), radius);
        this.xvel = xvel;
        this.yvel = yvel;
        this.timeframe = timeframe;
        new Thread(this).start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(moving) {
            move(xvel, yvel);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(timeframe);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }       
    }

    public double getX() {
        return getCenter().getX();
    }

    public double getY() {
        return getCenter().getY();
    }

    public void setXvel(double xvel) {
        this.xvel = xvel;
    }
    public void setYvel(double yvel) {
        this.yvel = yvel;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    // a Ball fields getter
    class Getter implements Runnable{
        Ball ball;
        public Getter(Ball ball) {
            this.ball = ball;
        }
        public void run() {
            while(ball.isMoving()) {
                System.out.println(ball.getX() + " " + ball.getY());                    
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }

    }

    Ball ball = new Main().new Ball(0, 0, 1, .5, .5, 1000);
    Thread getter = new Thread(new Getter(ball));
    getter.start();

}
}
```

And i like putting the moving mecanism inside of the constructor because it looks more natural with respect to what i am modeling, that is a moving ball that need not an external actor to make it move!